# PHP : Unidentified index : productOptionValue

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
foreach($optionValue['productOptionValue'] as $value): // error here

endforeach;
```

The index already exists.
Don't know what am I doing wrong.

```
  Array
(
    [optionValues] => Array
        (
            [34] => Array
                (
                    [id_product_option] => 1
                    [option_value] => Hello
                    [required] => 1
                    [productOptionValue] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id_product_option_value] => 1
                                    [id_option_value] => 88
                                    [quantity] => 12
                                    [subtract] => 1
                                    [price] => 232.0000
                                    [price_prefix] => r
                                    [weight] => 23.00000000
                                    [weight_prefix] => k
                                )

                        )

                )
```

Please help!!

Comment: it should be `$optionValue[34]['productOptionValue']`

Comment: try this `foreach($optionValue[34]['productOptionValue'] as $value){ }`

Answer (score 0):

You have an object with the property "optionValues" inside as far as I can read. Lets assume your initial variable is called "$sexy" :

```
$sexy = Array
(
[optionValues] => Array
    (
        [34] => Array
            (
                [id_product_option] => 1
                [option_value] => Hello
                [required] => 1
                [productOptionValue] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id_product_option_value] => 1
                                [id_option_value] => 88
                                [quantity] => 12
                                [subtract] => 1
                                [price] => 232.0000
                                [price_prefix] => r
                                [weight] => 23.00000000
                                [weight_prefix] => k
                            )

                    )

            )
```

So the following should do the trick:

```
foreach($sexy['optionValues'][34]['productOptionValue'] as $value):
    // I should be nice now and not throw an error here
endforeach;
```